# Highlighting the multiple keywords

Tags: c#, asp.net, highlight

Iam trying to highlight the multiple keywords in gridview.I tried with forloop but it highlight only the first item from the array.

```
    protected string HighlightText(string searchWord, string inputText)
    {

        // string[] strArray = new string[] { "Hello", "Welcome" };
        string s = "d,s";
        // Split string on spaces.
        // ... This will separate all the words.
        string[] words = s.Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(word);
            searchWord = words[i];
            Regex expression = new Regex(searchWord.Replace(" ", "|"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            return expression.Replace(inputText, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceKeywords));
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Advance thanks.

This was the out put Iam getting only the keyword "d" get highlighted I need to highlight keyword "s" also...

[image]

Comment: `return` inside the loop terminates its execution in the first iteration.

Comment: Instead of this return you should probably have `inputText =  expression.Replace(inputText, ...)` and at the end (after the loop): `return inputText;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try something like this, instead of looping for keywords 1 by 1

```
string inputText = "this is keyword1 for test and keyword4 also";

Regex keywords = new Regex("keyword1|keyword2|keyword3|keyword4");
//keywords = keywords.Replace("|", "\b|\b"); //or use \b between keywords

foreach (Match match in keywords.Matches(inputText))
{
   //get match.Index & match.Length for selection and color it
}
```

Comment: Thanks.I got answer,I just change my comma from the keyword string and change it to Pipe symbol then it works fine for me .Thanks for your great idea I got this idea from your answer.